# How to smooth adjacent faces

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, edges

I'm a first time blender user trying to make an engagement ring from scratch.

While making the ring I did a boolean cut, along the inside of the ring, which I think added some hard edges into my ring.

In this picture you can see how the faces, around the sides, are triangulated.
[image: the harsh edges]

How can I smooth these adjacent faces out so they don't have such noticeable edges between each other?

**Things I have tried:**

- Subdivision surface

  - The edges are too noticeable for what I would like, so I need to fix the mesh more beforehand
    [image: subdivision surface showing harsh edges]
- Laplacian smooth modifier

  - I tried setting the following vertex group
    [image]
  - Then doing a laplacian smooth in the Y axis on it.
  - There seems to be a little bit of improvement but I haven't been able get the harsh edges to go away
    [image: After applying a laplacian smooth on the y axis]
- Eye balling it

  - This seemed to be a bit fruitful but it will take me forever to edit all of the vertices

Comment: Have you tried using Right Click > Shade Smooth?

Comment: Although that does help a little bit, it doesn't help me with my underlying  mesh issues